Find vector perpendicular to a two-dimensional vector at a certain point
How could I find the vector, $\mathbf{u}$, perpendicular to a two-dimensional vector, $\mathbf{v}$, at a certain point $(x_1,y_1)$?

The vector $\mathbf u$ depends only on $\mathbf v$. The coordinates of the point are irrelevant. What do you know about perpendicular vectors in the plane?

Assuming we are talking about vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, you can use the property that a vector $\mathbf{u}$ is perpendicular to another vector $\mathbf{v}$ if their dot product is $0$: $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = u_{1} v_{1} + u_{2} v_{2} = 0$, where I define $\mathbf{u} = (u_{1}, u_{2}), \mathbf{v} = (v_{1}, v_{2})$.
Assuming you know $\mathbf{v}$, this will give you a linear equation for $\mathbf{u}$, although note that you won't get a unique solution. In fact, the vectors that form the line perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$ will all satisfy this equation.
